# Javascript EventKey function restriction between language switching

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that works on EventKey.the function is written in a way that ";" and dot "." are disabled on the keyboard but there is a problem when i switch to arabic keyboard the letters that are placed on the place of ";" ". " are also disabled but i need to enable them.I need to know how to mention that we are using an arabic keyboard in way that when i click these two keycodes the arabic letters should be enabled so when i press these two keys the arabic letters would be written but in english these same two keys are disabled.
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "onkeypress" instead of "onkeydown" or "onkeyup", then check the event "charCode".

Comment: i've tried it didn't work it still stay disabled when i click